# Vue JS: this.$emit returns undefined in console

Tags: vue.js

I have this in my `Home.vue` :

```
    <script>
export default {
    component: SurveyBox,
    name: 'HomeUser',
    props: {
        role: String,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            isLoggedIn: false,
            FirstUser: "Lucky",
            SecondUser: "Dan",
            AdminUser: "Admin"
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handleLogin: function(){
            if(this.username != '' && this.password != ''){
                if (this.username == 'Lucky' && this.password == 'test') {
                    this.isLoggedIn = true;
                    this.$router.replace('/');
                    this.$emit("Lucky", this.FirstUser)
                    console.log(this.$emit("authenticated", true))
                }else if (this.username == 'Dan' && this.password == 'test') {
                    this.isLoggedIn = true;
                    this.$router.replace('/');
                    this.$emit("Dan", this.SecondUser)
                    console.log(this.$emit("Dan", this.SecondUser))
                }else if(this.username == 'Admin' && this.password == 'admin'){
                    this.isLoggedIn = true;
                    this.$router.replace('/')
                    this.$emit("Admin", this.AdminUser)
                    console.log(this.$emit("Admin", true))
                }
            }else{
                console.log(this.$emit)
            }

        }
    },
}
</script>
```

I just want to pass the `FirstUser, SecondUser, AdminUser,` in the parent component. As I console.log the `this.$emit` it returns undefined. Why is that happening?

Here in my Parent Component which is `App.vue`. I wanna catch `this.$emit` through methods in `setAuthenticated` function.

```
    <template>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div v-if="openNavbar" class="sidenav" style="">
      <h1 @click="openNavbar = !openNavbar"><u>=</u></h1>
      <p><router-link to="/">Home</router-link></p>
      <p><router-link to="/find-user">Find User</router-link></p>
      <p v-if="Lucky"><FirstLinkRouter/></p>
      <p v-else-if="Dan"><SecondLinkRouter/></p>
      <p v-else-if="Admin"><AdminLinkRouter/></p>
    </div>
    <div v-else style="">
      <h1 @click="openNavbar = !openNavbar"><u>=</u></h1>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;">
      <router-view @roles="setAuthenticated"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      component: [FirstLinkRouter, SecondLinkRouter, AdminLinkRouter],
      openNavbar: false,
      roles: "",
    }
  },
  methods: {
        setAuthenticated(status) {
        this.roles = status;
        console.log(status)
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: May I know the reason of asking asking same question multiple times ? You already asked same question yesterday : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71687440/passing-parameters-in-emit-is-undefined/71687880#71687880

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I changed the code so I thought, I should post a new question. And get answers. Sorry if it's redundant.

Comment: I did not see any difference in both the questions.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I tried doing the solution you give to me but the this.$emit still not passing the parameters and returns undefined in my console.

Comment: This question looks identical to the previous one. If you didn't get satisfactory solution, you can edit the previous question to explain a little bit more clearly what the problem is and what you tried. Don't repost questions as this will quickly lead you to question ban